# realtime midi input and synchronisation with audio

Tags: audio, midi, audiounit, vst

I have built a standalone app version of a project that until now was just a VST/audiounit. I am providing audio support via [rtaudio](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtaudio).

I would like to add MIDI support using [rtmidi](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~gary/rtmidi/) but it's not clear to me how to synchronise the audio and MIDI parts.

In VST/audiounit land, I am used to MIDI events that have a timestamp indicating their offset in samples from the start of the audio block.

rtmidi provides a delta time in seconds since the previous event, but I am not sure how I should grab those events and how I can work out their time in relation to the current sample in the audio thread.

How do plugin hosts do this?

I can understand how events can be sample accurate on playback, but it's not clear how they could be sample accurate when using realtime input.

rtaudio gives me a callback function. I will run at a low block size (32 samples). I guess I will pass a pointer to an rtmidi instance as the userdata part of the callback and then call midiin->getMessage( &message ); inside the audio callback, but I am not sure if this is thread-sensible.

Many thanks for any tips you can give me

Comment: MIDI will never be sample accurate, nor does it need to be.  MIDI data is relatively slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, you don't need to worry about it. Your program should send the MIDI events to the plugin with a timestamp of zero as soon as they arrive. I think you have perhaps misunderstood the idea behind what it means to be "sample accurate".

As @Brad noted in his comment to your question, MIDI is indeed very slow. But that's only part of the problem... when you are working in a block-based environment, incoming MIDI events cannot be processed by the plugin until the start of a block. When computers were slower and block sizes of 512 (or god forbid, >1024) were common, this introduced a non-trivial amount of latency which results in the arrangement not sounding as "tight". Therefore sequencers came up with a clever way to get around this problem. Since the MIDI events are already known ahead of time, these events can be sent to the instrument one block early with an offset in sample frames. The plugin then receives these events at the start of the block, and knows not to start actually processing them until `N` samples have passed. This is what "sample accurate" means in sequencers.

However, if you are dealing with live input from a keyboard or some sort of other MIDI device, there is no way to "schedule" these events. In fact, by the time you receive them, the clock is already ticking! Therefore these events should just be sent to the plugin at the start of the very next block with an offset of 0. Sequencers such as Ableton Live, which allow a plugin to simultaneously receive both pre-sequenced and live events, simply send any live events with an offset of 0 frames.

Since you are using a very small block size, the worst-case scenario is a latency of .7ms, which isn't too bad at all. In the case of rtmidi, the timestamp does not represent an offset which you need to schedule around, but rather the time which the event was captured. But since you only intend to receive live events (you *aren't* writing a sequencer, are you?), you can simply pass any incoming MIDI to the plugin right away.